# How to override each file in a folder to a specific client code in VIsual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Ok let met try and explain what I want to achieve.

I have a folder structure in my Project namely

```
Views -> Directory
-----ClientOneOverride -> Directory
----------------------Home.cshtml -> File
----------------------About.cshtml -> File
-----Home.cshtml -> File
-----About.cshtml -> File
-----Contact.cshtml -> File
```

When I build the project and I pass a key stating I want to ClientOneOverride to be built. I want Visual Studio to buil the base files in the Views directory and then override them with the CLientOneOverride folders contents.

So in this example I would want VS to build `Home.cshtml, About.cshtml, Contact.cshtml` and then override `Home.cshtml and About.cshtml` with whats in the ClientOneOverride directory because the specific client's `Contact.cshtml` is the same as the base version. Is this possible or not?

I want to do this to ensure that the logic stays the same across all clients, but just their front-ends changes.

*****UPDATE******

I will try and explain what I am trying to achieve.

I have a MVC projects, this project contains the default folder structure such as

```
Controllers
Models
View
```

I have multiple clients that I am building this project for, but as you know each has their own idea of how their site should look like. I don't blame them.

So what I want to do is write a base version of the site and then write client specific sections such as the following.

In my Views folder I have a `.cshtml` file called `Index.cshtml` this view is a partial view and contain just a few div's and whatever. This `Index.cshtml` file is the base file, so each client will have the look and feel of this file. Say for instance of my client's wants to have their own look and feel of the `Index.cshtml` file I want to be able to allow them to customize it. So then in the `Views` folder I would create another folder with the clients name, let's call this client `ClientA`.

So the folder structure would look something like this

```
Views                    ----This is the base folder
-----ClientA             ----Client specific folder inside the base folder
------------Index.cshtml ----Client specific file override
-----Index.cshtml        ----Base file if client does not want a custom override of the normal look and feel.
```

Now what I want to do is the following. After I have built the base and then built each client specific way of their implementation of the look and feel I only want to `Build -- Visual Studio Build` their specific feature set.

So if I am building the application for ClientA --> I first want all the base files to be build by Visual Studio, then I want Visual studio to run through the `Views` folder agian and then if their is a `ClientA` override it should replace the base file with the overridden file.

So before the build process kicks of I want to specify for which client the build should be made.

I hope someone is following me, and that someone does understand what I am trying to achieve.

I know with a GULP job this is achievable, but I want to do it in Visual Studio.

Is this even remotely possible?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but post-build action seems to be a solution?

Comment: @slawekwin I also thought about that, but how would I go about doing it to override the current files, if it requires a client specific file.

Comment: you know the path to the file, don't you? wouldn't something like "xcopy Views\ClientOneOverride\*.* Views /Y" work?

Comment: Yes that will work, but it would replace them, but it would still keep the folder as well. Can't seem to find a good site where most of these examples are shown.

Comment: I don't seem to understand the problem you are now talking about.

Comment: I will edit my post to reflect my actual question.

Comment: @slawekwin I have updated my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97472/discussion-between-theunis-and-slawekwin).